# Sufi Dance in Turkey

Tags: turkey, culture, religion

I'm looking for a Sufi dance show in Istanbul. I'd like to watch for a "real and non-hollywood" show. I don't need dinner nor drinks nor any kind of extras.

Comment: Your question is not an exact duplicate of this question [http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/8770/what-are-some-non-indian-and-non-middle-eastern-sufi-destinations-around-the-wor/8774#8774], however the accepted answer indicates links to Sufi sites and places where Sufi dancing can be seen in Istanbul. I think you should have a look there.

Answer (score 3):

Tom Broshanan lists [several venues in Istanbul](http://www.turkeytravelplanner.com/go/Istanbul/Sights/Beyoglu/mevlevi_program.html).

I have never done it. I once wanted to attend a show near Avanos, bit it was unfortunately cancelled because of a lack of attendees.

P.S. I think the best place to see Whirling Dervishes is [Konya](http://www.turkeytravelplanner.com/go/CentralAnatolia/Konya/index.html). It seems to be [on your way](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/16053/getting-from-goreme-to-denizli-by-car) ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I am from istanbul . you can find  Sufi dance  near blue mosque in İstanbul. @user3470 is right . best place is Konya for see Whirling Dervishes .

I found this website. I hope help you :

http://www.istanbuldanceensemble.com/2/
http://www.sehirfirsati.com/deals/istanbul/istanbulliveproduction/622424
same place.

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you about the ones in Istanbul.

Hodjapasha is working on daily basis and I find it very serious and real. Or if you are in town on Sundays you can check the one at Galata Mevlevihanesi, at the end of the Istiklal Street close to the Tunnel station.

Besides that I totally agree that best option is in Konya but still the people doing it in Istanbul are mostly from there. Are they doing this for commercial purposes? Yes. Is it impressive? Yes again.